# WebHost failed to process a request for Lists web service

Tags: web-services, windows-authentication

I get the following error when I try to access the SharePoint 2010 List web service in a web application. This error happens only when I have Kerberos as the authentication provider. If I change to NTLM the error goes away. Any ideas?

```
Description:
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/45523402
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/_vti_bin/ListData.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Security settings for this service require Windows Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Security settings for this service require Windows Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.ApplyHostedContext(VirtualPathExtension virtualPathExtension, Boolean isMetadataListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncodingBindingElement.InternalBuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WebMessageEncodingBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListener[TChannel]()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.MaybeCreateListener(Boolean actuallyCreate, Type[] supportedChannels, Binding binding, BindingParameterCollection parameters, Uri listenUriBaseAddress, String listenUriRelativeAddress, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, ServiceThrottle throttle, IChannelListener& result, Boolean supportContextSession)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildChannelListener(StuffPerListenUriInfo stuff, ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Uri listenUri, ListenUriMode listenUriMode, Boolean supportContextSession, IChannelListener& result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 6740
```

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, make sure that Windows Authentication is enabled.  Then click the Advanced Settings for Windows Authentication and try changing the "Enabled Kernel-Mode authentication" option.

Comment: Windows authentication is enabled and I tired Enable Kernel-Mode authentication on and off.

Comment: Do you have ASP.NET Impersonation on or off?

Comment: Yes ASP.NET Impersonation is on

Comment: Does it make a difference off?

Comment: Restart IIS and also check your central admin settings.
Cheers